# GradientDrawable.setStroke width doesn't seem to be working correctly

Tags: android, frameworks

When you assign a drawable to a view using the xml with a stroke width, it works fine.
When I try to assign it dynamically during runtime and change the stroke width, it doesn't seem to work.

You can find the result and the code as snapshots [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ubqc6.jpg)

Basically,

Left view is initialized with a background drawable with a stroke width of 40px through the xmls.

Center view is just a basic view with a background color RED and a height of 40px

Right view is a basic view that is assigned a background drawable programmatically and the stroke width is changed to 40px on the press of the button.

You can clearly see in the result that the left view's border width is the same as the center view's height while the right view's border width is about half the size of the others... what am I doing wrong? Or is it a bug in android's sdk?

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: Seems like a bug in SDK. I did some trick to fix that. In the first time append view to layout I added transparent stroke .After that when change stroke dynamically It works fine

Comment: I also have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Question is too old but i hope i wll help to someone. I think there is only one solution. You should set size of `GradientDrawable` again using this method:

```
gradientDrawable.setStroke(100, Color.RED);
gradientDrawable.setSize(gradientDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),gradientDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
```